# What does "expensive fate" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, lyrics

In Pop Singer Billie Eilish's song, there are the lyrics "Maybe it's in the gutter/Where I left my lover./*What an expensive fate!*". What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because she is taking the point of view of a serial killer who has literally killed her lover, ***What an expensive fate*** probably refers to her own fate. The price she will pay is high, because the police know about her and are coming for her soon, and she will be sentenced to death for killing her friends.

It's not a convincing pathology of a serial killer, but not bad for a 15-year-old songwriter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you listen to her singing the acoustic version the line is

> What an expensive fake,

which probably means she poured a lot of time and effort into something that was ultimately worthless/not what she thought it was, like her revenge or even the original relationship.